# Unit test for integer attribute validation for an Entity Framework object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, validation

How to create a unit test to an Entity Framework object to verify an integer attribute validation annotated with the [required] key like this:

```
[Required]
public Int32 MyIntProperty { get; set; }
```

The unit test code should be something like this:

```
        EntityObject entityObject = new EntityObject();
        entityObject.MyIntProperty = null;

        EntityObjectContext.EntityObject.Attach(entityObject);
        EntityObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entityObject, EntityState.Added);
        var dbContext = new DbContext(EntityObjectContext, true);

        int errors = dbContext.GetValidationErrors().Count();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, errors);
```

The problem is that I can not indicate the null value to an integer property. Is it possible to tests this validation another way?
Tks.

Comment: since your property cannot be null you don't need the Required argument - there is nothing to test here.

Comment: My property can be empty when is used in context of a web request, when the model of the controller is MyEntityObject. Maybe this is just not the better way of testing validations in an ASP.net MVC application.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what "empty" means in the context of non-nullable int. If the value is 0 - how do you distinguish whether it was initialized to 0 by CLR or someone set it to 0?

Comment: By empty I mean no values in the correspondence in the ViewModel and the html form in an MVC .Net context. I think the MVC .Net framework just validate if the property in question is updated by any value from the HTML form. If not then the [Required] annotation indicate invalid value for the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem by testing if the property was annotated by the [Required] key word:

```
        var propertyInfo = typeof(EntityObject).GetProperty("MyIntProperty");

        var attribute = (EdmScalarPropertyAttribute) 
                        propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
                                typeof(EdmScalarPropertyAttribute), true)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

        Assert.IsFalse(attribute.IsNullable);
```

If anyone have other solution please tell me.
Tks.

Answer (score 1):

If the validation fails only on `null` then there is nothing to test here, as `Int32` will never be `null`. If you want to make it possible to be `null` change it's type to `Int32?` (or better: `int?`). If the validation fails for some other reasons, then don't put `null` into your property but some other erroneous value.

Answer (score 1):

`Int32` cannot be `null` unless it `Int32?`.

I don't know if the following suits your requirement but Int32 would be 0 when not initialised.

`Assert.AreNotEqual(0, error);`

Comment: It can also be 0 when initialized to 0.